# How to save a SMS in a database

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to save some SMS' in a SQLite database from a remote server using an XML parser. I am using `urlencode()` on server side (PHP) and `URLDecoder.decode()` on Android. Some of the special characters are replaced by � in the database.

I searched a lot and found that we need to convert UTF-8 to a GSM 7 bit encoding and some similar posts. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

### EDIT:

Here is an example of SMS which is encoded using `urlencode()`

> I+Am+Da+Witness+2+His+Fearless+Death+I+Am+A+Token+Of+His+Last+Promise+**%96**+4giveness+I+Am+Da+CROSS+Blessings+On+Good+Friday...

that %96 is not supported by `URLDecoder.decode()`

Comment: Most likely you're not using the same character encoding in both XML and DB.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have added an example. I am using utf-8 for xml. But not sure how to check encoding type for an SQLite database

Comment: You can set SQLite DB encoding using `PRAGMA`, as specified in [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding). Also keep in mind that `String` in Java is Unicode by default. You need to specify UTF-8 when storing it (e.g. `new String("Hello", "UTF-8")`. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

Comment: I think `URLDecoder.decode()` can decode all the `%xx`  listed here. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If SQLite is not UTF-8, when you recover the characters, they will be corrupt.

Comment: yes, SQLite is utf-8 by default. Is it possible to print characters like å è ð in xml ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to set up the correct coding on XML header so the parser will know what encoding to use.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have already used that. Now I am using `utf8_encode()` which skipped %96 as its neither ASCII nor UTF-8. IS there any way to preserve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the text editor to use `utf-8 without BOM` and it worked!

Comment: LOL text editor? Which text editor are your talking about? :P

Comment: yes. the SQLite and xml is set to use utf-8 but the text editor which I used to edit xml is saving xml in ANSI encoding type. That was the issue.

Comment: Well, you never stated that in your question, so obviously you're the only one who can answer that xD

Comment: @m0skit0, there are a lot of possibilities for a problem and will be different in different situations. May be this question will help someone who followed like my path :)